# Wix Installer Harvest Error in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix

I'm really needing some assistance. I'm using VS 2012, which I chose Wix Toolset v3.9 as the deployment method for my VB.NET application. I have ran into an issue that I've spent hours on and hoping I can get some assistance from fellow devs out there. To mention now, I'm using an HP.

I have Created A Setup Project (Wix) and it has successfully created a project for the Wix installer in my solution. When I go to build it, it spits out the following error:

"Build error during harvesting: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(609,5): The OutputPath property is not set for project (myapplication).  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform='MCD'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project.

File: heat.exe"

I came across articles related to the MCD being associated to HP computers, so I figured I'd mention this too. Really, I just need to create a .exe installer and am having one heck of a hard time with this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have a look at this answer, by Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100238/the-outputpath-property-is-not-set-for-this-project-error