# The OutputPath property is not set for this project for a project in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild

First off I looked at these two

[the outputpath property is not set for this project error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100238/the-outputpath-property-is-not-set-for-this-project-error)
and 
[the outputpath property is not set for this project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086795/the-outputpath-property-is-not-set-for-this-project)

The error I am getting is:

```
Set Property: _InvalidConfigurationMessageText=The OutputPath property is not set for 
project 'NutritionAdminWeb.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified 
a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  
Platform='AnyCPU'.
```

The issue I have with the solutions list above is that most of them are changes to the project or solution files.  However, I work in a team of five and we use TFS and I am the only machine that is having the issue.

Also to be clear what I get is a build failed with 0 errors.  I only found the message by putting on Build Output to verbose.

So I tried

- changing the Platform from "Any CPU" to "AnyCPU"
- looking for a Platform variable in my environment variables (there was none)
- looking for any bad references

The other machines also have the Platform ="Any CPU"

What else can I check that would be machine specific that would generate this error message?

I posted the file because someone asked.  I also try adding a Property group

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|Any CPU' ">
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<Optimize>false</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
<IncludeIisSettings>false</IncludeIisSettings>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But again, long term, I am against modifying the project file as it is working for others.  But willing to try one off ideas.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{54F80285-BFCA-4CA5-A53F-8FDC26C316EA}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>NutritionAdminWeb</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>NutritionAdminWeb</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <IISExpressSSLPort>44305</IISExpressSSLPort>
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>false</IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>
    <TargetOfficeVersion>15.0</TargetOfficeVersion>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <IncludeIisSettings>false</IncludeIisSettings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="<Removed for posting>, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\<Removed for posting></HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="<Removed for posting> Version=5.0.6005.15557, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\<Removed for posting></HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="<Removed for posting>, Version=5.0.6005.15557, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\<Removed for posting></HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="<Removed for posting>Version=2.0.0.16, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\<Removed for posting></HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="<Removed for posting> Version=5.0.6005.15558, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\<Removed for posting></HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Grid.Mvc.Ajax">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Grid.Mvc.Ajax.1.0.22\lib\Grid.Mvc.Ajax.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="GridMvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Grid.Mvc.Redux.1.0.2\lib\GridMvc.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\log4net.1.2.13.0\lib\log4net.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Extensions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69c3241e6f0468ca, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=15.0.0.0">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime, Version=15.0.0.0">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Helpers">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers.3.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Web.Helpers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\MenuNutritionCore\bin\Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.IdentityModel" />
    <Reference Include="<Removed for posting> Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\<Removed for posting></HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
    <Reference Include="System.Security" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages<Removed for posting></HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3\lib\net40\System.Web.Optimization.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Abstractions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Routing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WebRequest">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.0\lib\net45\System.Web.Helpers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.0\lib\net45\System.Web.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Routing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.0\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.0\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.0\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.0.0\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WebGrease">
      <HintPath>..\packages\WebGrease.1.6.0\lib\WebGrease.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="App_Start\BundleConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\FilterConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\RouteConfig.cs" />
   <Removed for posting>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap.min.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\Gridmvc.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\gridmvc.datepicker.css" />
    <Removed for posting>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
  <Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
  </Target>
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>9466</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost:2733/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it.
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target> -->
</Project>
```

**Solved**

This was resolved by uninstalling and reinstalling 2015.  What is odd is I did not uninstall any .net programs, my profile, or tfs components.  So upon reinstalling my start page look the same I just open the project as normal and my additional add-ons like Build Vision are still installed.

Comment: Could you reproduce that issue with new projects? What's the result if you remove other project references? Post detail code of NutritionAdminWeb.csproj file.

Comment: Could you reproduce that issue with new projects? No.   What's the result if you remove other project references? Don't want to do that because the project is in tfs and works for others, I can say there are no yellow triangles next to any of the references

Comment: Do you download/map all related projects to local? What's the result if you just build all related projects?

Comment: Getting exact same error in VS2015 project (no errors/warnings/messages). Was working fine, now suddenly not. No changes to project files from repo on Azure DevOps (recently installed VS2019...) Will uninstall/reinstall...

Comment: I solved it by running the VS2015 installer and clicking on "Repair".. voila..back to normal