# Unable to build SSRS Project

Tags: reporting-services, azure-devops

I am trying to set up a build pipeline in Azure DevOPS to build a SSRS project. I have a VSBuild task setup like so

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:OutDir="bin\Debug" /p:OutputPath="bin\Debug" /verbosity:diagnostic'
    configuration: '$(configuration)'
```

I am getting the following error

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Reporting
> Services\Microsoft.ReportingServices.MSBuilder.targets(30,5): Error
> MSB4018: The "ReportBuilderTask" task failed unexpectedly
> System.ArgumentException: The OutputPath property cannot be blank. It
> must provide a relative path that is a child folder under the path of
> the report server project.    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.BuildProcess.ReportProjectOptions.GetOutputDirectory()
> at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.BuildProcess.ReportProjectOptions.GetOutputFile(String
> fileName)    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.BuildProcess.Builder.BuildReport(ReportReportNode
> node, ReportProjectOptions options, IMessageHandler messageHandler,
> ICheckPublish checkPublish)    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.BuildProcess.Builder.BuildItems(ICollection
> collection, ReportProjectOptions options, IMessageHandler
> messageHandler, ICheckPublish checkPublish)    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.BuildProcess.ReportBuilderTask.Execute()
> at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()

I checked the PropertyGroup for my configuration and I do see OutputPath, I am also supplying it as an MSBuild parameter additionally, but it isn't getting picked up it seems.

What am I missing? I am using the hosted agent.

Comment: This seems to say that you need to have some configuration in the actual project file. Which defeats the purpose of having a cmd line option I know, but perhaps try it and see if it makes a difference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100238/the-outputpath-property-is-not-set-for-this-project-error

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank you for your comment. I tried adding that as well to the property group matching the condition. Didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the error message, the path cannot be full path. The azure devops variables carry full absolute paths. I have changed the OutputPath property to carry the relative path and things seem to work now.